# CakePHP: Data not being sent to extension views when paging via Paginator helper

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I have a simple table of results being displayed that is paged in records of 25. There are 350 results, and the next, 1, 2, 3 page navigation links work perfectly for paging my data. To re-iterate, I am using the standard Paginator component and helpers to create these paging links.

The problem arises when I parse the same results to my .csv extension view & layout. If I do not click a page number (so I am on the default, first 25 records page) and I click my export to CSV icon, all of the results are perfectly rendered in my csv extension view, and my CSV file created successfully. However, whenever I have paged, it no longer picks up the results, which is strange.

For example: somehost.com/controller/action/1.csv will send all the records to my csv extension view, whereas somehost.com/controller/action/1/page:5.csv will still pick up the view and layout for the csv extension, but the data is empty.

Is there some configuration setting I need to add to the Paginator component / helper to work with different extension layouts and views? After all, the extensions (and therefore layouts and views) utilize the exact same controller, the idea of MVC being that the controller should be passing the data along to my csv view no matter what.

Any help, suggestions and ideas always appreciated.

Comment: is your goal to have only say page 5 displaying records 125-150 exported to csv?

Comment: @swiecki - Yes, that is correct. Basically any paged results will simply be exported as they see them.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion for a workaround:

You could have an action in your controller that takes a page value as a parameter and then pass that into a find:

```
function csvgenerator($page){
$this->layout = 'csvlayout';
$this->set('variableForView',$this->Model->find('all',array(
    'conditions' => array('Model.field' => $thisValue), //array of conditions
    'order' => array('Model.field1 DESC'), //string or array defining order
    'limit' => n, //int
    'page' => $page //int
));
}
```

Comment: I had considered this, however I'd prefer to avoid it, the idea being that any view of data can be sent straight to any extension. I thought that's the idea with using extensions. Your idea is not a bad one, and it will indeed work. Thank you for that.